# what is /dev/block/by-name?

Tags: android, linux

I used `adb shell`
then `ls /dev/block/by-name`

but I want to konw how is `/dev/block/by-name` created? And what is by-name?
It's better to tell me the source code path.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.startpage.com/sp/search?query=linux+device+file+system&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files under `/dev/block/by-name` are symbolic links to disk partitions.

For example the system partition is `/dev/block/by-name/system` and the vendor partition is `/dev/block/by-name/vendor`.

It was added in 2018 in [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/8eec38f4e463d8cd980562ec49432c17972cc5cb). You can also find a detailed explanation there. Because it was added in 2018 these symlinks don't exist in older Android versions.

It is also said that this is an Android feature and not a general Linux feature.

Comment: It is a general Linux feature but Android uses slightly different naming. Mainline Linux uses `/dev/disk`, the equivalent is `/dev/disk/by-label`.

Comment: @Thaodan This might be true but the exact path name `/dev/block/by-name` only exists on Android.

Comment: @Thaodan Also note that the disk label is not the same as the Android partition name.

Comment: disk label aren't 100% the same but it is very much the same except that labels are not hardcoded.

Comment: I don't see how the exact path name of /dev/block/by-name only exists in Android, /dev/disk/* uses the same mechanism, infact you can read the same property in udev and recreate the same folder with Udev.